# Using web3py with truffle framework

Tags: truffle, web3.py

Can we use web3.py with Truffle framework ?
If yes, please share such integration examples

Answer (score 1):

[Truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle) is a Javascript framework and [web3.py](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py) is a Python library.  Getting them to work together would be more hassle than it's worth, especially considering there is also a [web3js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) library.

If you are looking for Truffle-like functionality but prefer to code in Python, I would suggest checking out [Brownie](https://github.com/iamdefinitelyahuman/brownie).  It offers many similar features to Truffle.

Disclaimer: I am the lead developer for Brownie.

Comment: I highly recommend `Brownie` it is pretty functional and useful